# How to organise content using public, private and semi-private groups?

Tags: 7

I'm building a community website with [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) and I need to be able to create 3 kinds of groups:

- public groups : anyone can view content, group members only can post/edit/delete content
- private groups : group members only can view/post/edit/delete content
- semi-private groups : authenticated users can view content, group members only can post/edit/delete content

How can I achieve this?

Comment: create a role of every group type and assign permission

Comment: Thanks Adi. But I'm not sure to understand your proposition: you mean that I could assign a group-type-based role to each user? Maybe I should mention that a user can belong to several groups, whatever their type.

Answer (score 0):

The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For this specific question, you'd enable the `gnode` submodule, and for each group type you would define the appropriate permissions (view, edit, delete, etc) for the various Content Types. That's it.

For more details about the various types of roles used by the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".